# How Can I compare table column by convert it first in postgresql + typeorm

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, query-builder, date-format

I am beginner in Backend technology and I am developing one query in `Typeorm QueryBuilder` + PostgreSQL.

My query is look like this :

[image: YYYY-MM-DD]

But I can't convert my timestamp into following format. Can anyone who has expertise in it, please help me to select all records with timestamp in specific format.

I am suffering this things from last two days but still not find any solution. Actually I want to compare this date format in `having` clause. so I want to first select that date format then I can use that same method to compare column with current date and previous dates.

Comment: Is `h.timestamp` a timestamp or string field?

Comment: What is the data type for the column `timestamp`? If it is timestamp or date then you do not use `to_date` (as it is already that). What you want is `to_char(column, format)/ So try ``to_char(h.timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd').